# does within mean near the parameters or at the exact spot?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, "tape or tab shut within 1" of lead/trail edge" mean at exactly 1" or near the 1"? Would being 2" from the edge be acceptable because it just means to not go over the 1" or does it have to be at exactly that 1" mark?

Comment: If they were being technically precise, it would be the whole disc of radius 1”, excluding the perimeter.

Comment: Within usually means inside, so in the above use it means at or less than 1 inch away.

Comment: As Barmar says it means at or inside the 1” line, so 2” would not be good because it is *more* than 1” away.  But 0.5 inches would be acceptable.

Comment: @Lawrence: in this case, "from the edge" indicates a region including the entire area up to an inch on each side of said edge.

Comment: @Conrado Yes, that's right. Because the object was a tape, I was 'modeling' it as a line, with the 'edge' being the point where the tape ended. So anything inside a 1" circle of that point would be included, but anything precisely 1" from the edge would be excluded. However, English is more fluid than that, so it can be ambiguous whether the speaker intends to include points precisely 1" from the edge.

Comment: If looking up the definition of the word [*within*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/within) doesn't answer your question, what are you actually asking?